Error laravel deploy railway
tengo un serio problema al intentar desplegar una aplicacion laravel en railway que ya estoy cansado de batallar, el problema es que no se conecta a la base de datos de railway aun cuando estan todas las variables de entorno correctas,adjunto imagen del errorm espero que alguien me pueda ayudar :(

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
